# How many GPUs in my machine?

Tags: command-line, gpu

I wonder how I can know how many GPUs on my machine with and without using terminal?

Answer (score 10):

## Terminal way

Type this:

```
lspci|grep 'VGA\|Display'
```

and you'll see something similar like this:

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c9)
```

You can ignore `grep 'VGA\|Display'` to list all PCIe and figure out how many GPUs you have by yourself if somehow the data is inaccurate.

## GUI way

Install `hardinfo` and run it on terminal/search in Dash for "System Profiler and Benchmark". Look at the PCI devices section. It should looks like this:

[image: GUI]

Comment: `grep VGA` is a bad idea: on my system I have two GPUs: discrete nVidia and built-in Intel, and only one shows up as VGA compatible controller. It's better to use `lspci|grep 'VGA\|Display'`, so that the following line could be found: `00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`.

Answer (score 8):

## Terminal

#### Using `lspci`

Most desktop computing GPUs (i. e. the target group of Ubuntu) are available and enumerated through the PCI bus.

A quick and easy to remember command is

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] (rev a1)
```

In the odd case that some other device has `VGA` in its name or vendor string you can scan specifically for the VGA adapter device class code:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -Fe '[0300]:'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF104 [GeForce GTX 460] [10de:0e22] (rev a1)
```

#### Using `lshw`

The advantage of `lshw` is that it enumerates devices on *all* known interfaces incl. USB, FireWire, Thunderbolt, I2C and other decreasingly common buses for GPUs on *desktop* computers (as opposed to embedded systems).

The disadvantage is that it requires super-user privileges to scan these buses.

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF104 [GeForce GTX 460]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:32 memory: ...
```

`-C display` restricts the device list to graphics adapters, not *displays* or screens as the device class name suggests.

Comment: In some cases this will not show GPUs that are not in use (e.g. on certain nvidia cards with multiple GPUs but no support from the driver).

Comment: `grep VGA` is a bad idea: on my system I have two GPUs: discrete nVidia and built-in Intel, and only one shows up as VGA compatible controller. It's better to use `lspci|grep 'VGA\|Display'`, so that the following line could be found: `00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`.

Answer (score 0):

## Terminal

#### Using `lspci`

You can use `lspci` to find GPUs, but the commands currently provided by other answers lose some of the results and show only one GPU — the primary one, VGA-compatible, used by BIOS/EFI to display its diagnostics.

To find both the default video card and secondary ones, you can use the following command:

```
$ lspci|grep 'VGA\|Display'
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
```

Even more general way is to use [PCI device class code](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD) instead of its textual representation:

```
$ lspci -nn|grep ' \[03..\]: '
00:02.0 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2)
```

Answer (score 0):

### `lspci`

I use `lspci` witk `-k` option for see kernel driver and kernel modules too, both.

After for `grep` I set `-A 2` parameter for two lines in a row after the info for keyword "VGA":

```
lspci -k|grep -iA2 "VGA"
```

Note: option `-i` in `grep` is for ignore case,
e. g. "vGA" or "vga".